# How to set the differenet intent in GCMListenerService?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to android development and now i am working on push notification. I want to send two different types of messages in GCM Push notification, Image and Text messages and I want to set the two different intents on the basis of message type. If it is a text message showTextMessage activity should be open and if it is image message, in message there will be a link of that image, and showImagesMessage activity should be open. how i can do that? or any other techniques? Please help me your help should be appreciated.

This is my PushReceiver Code:

```
public class GCMPushReceiverService extends GcmListenerService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    //Getting the message from the bundle
    String message = data.getString("message");
    String senderName=data.getString("sender_name");
    String senderID=data.getString("sender_id");
  //  String messageType=data.getString("message_type");
    //Displaying a notiffication with the message
    sendNotification(message,senderName,senderID);
}

private void sendNotification(String message,String senderName, String senderID) {

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_event_note_black_24dp;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, senderName+"\t"+message, when);
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    notification.sound=soundUri;
    String title = this.getString(R.string.app_name);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ShowMessage.class);
    Bundle extras=new Bundle();
    extras.putString("message",message);
    extras.putString("sender_name", senderName);
    extras.putString("sender_id",senderID);
    extras.putString("time", String.valueOf(when));
    notificationIntent.putExtras(extras);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, senderName, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}

@Override
public void onMessageSent(String msgId) {
    super.onMessageSent(msgId);
}
}
```

Comment: Don't send images like that. The message is limited to 4kbytes anyways. Upload the image to a server and send a link to download it. Also read about `onMessageReceived` here https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ to choose how to react to every message

Comment: Image is already uploaded on server. Sender will select the image and will send it to the receiver, on receiver side link of image will be received and then I want to set the intent on the basis of the message. Is it a link or a text message @UFCInsider

Comment: Always use text. I would prefix my message with an indicator, for example "[img]..." and "[text]..." and then inside `onMessageReceived` I would check for the prefix to determine the afterwards action